# How to add user data to my Recyclerview through onClick?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to build a simple To Do List app using a RecyclerView with a custom Adapter.  I've build a model data class to get and set my todos.  My problem is that each time I click the button to add my item, nothing happens.  I did call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method but it still doesn't work.

This is a practice app that I'm building to learn RecyclerViews and custom adapters so I'd appreciate it if someone could explain why it doesn't work and perhaps explain to me how I can fix it.

This is my code where I'm retrieving the user input from the EditText field and placing it in my data:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private ToDoData toDoData;

        private List<ToDoData> toDoList = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            final ToDoAdapter toDoAdapter = new ToDoAdapter(toDoList, this);
            toDoData = new ToDoData(this);

            final EditText toDoInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.add_todo);
            Button toDoAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_item);

            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            RecyclerView toDoDisplay = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.toDoDisplayRecyclerView);
            toDoDisplay.setAdapter(toDoAdapter);
            toDoDisplay.setHasFixedSize(true);
            toDoDisplay.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


            toDoAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    toDoData.setToDo(toDoInput.getText().toString());
                    toDoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

This is my model class with getters and setters.  The list-item has only 1 field so its rather small:

```
public class ToDoData {
    private String toDoString;

    public ToDoData(String todoString){
        this.toDoString = todoString;
    }

    public ToDoData(Context context){}

    public String getToDo() {
        return toDoString;
    }

    public void setToDo(String toDoString) {
        this.toDoString = toDoString;
    }
}
```

And this is my custom adapter.  I followed through a tutorial while building this but I do however think that my problem stems from the adapter:

```
public class ToDoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ToDoAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ToDoData> toDoList;
    private Context context;

    public ToDoAdapter(List<ToDoData> todoList, Context context) {
        this.toDoList = todoList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView todoView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            todoView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.to_do_display);
        }
    }

    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.to_do_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ToDoData todo = toDoList.get(position);

        holder.todoView.setText(todo.getToDo());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (toDoList == null) ? 0 : toDoList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: how do u add data to `toDoList` ? and where do u call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter? from your code, you have passed empty `toDoList` to the adapter !

Comment: @AtefHares Sorry correction*  I did call `notifyDataSetChanged` in my button onClick but it didn't work.

Comment: your `toDoList` is empty it does not have any items because you did not use `toDoList.add(toDoData)` and thus the `notifyDataSetChanged()` has no effect !

Comment: @AtefHares Thanks mate.  That makes more sense.  I've upvoted your comment.  If you think this question was well asked, can you give me an upvote as well?

Comment: @AtefHares is correct, the crux of the issue ToDoData not being part of the collection passed to the adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add one setter method in your adapter class for setting the collection and then invoke `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Declare the `ToDoAdapter` as class member and then invoke the setter function on `Button` click as follows,

```
adapter.setTodoList(/* pass collection */);
adapter.notifyDataSetchanged();
```

Comment: Kinda confused.  I'm retrieving the user input from my MainActivity.  How can I do that in the adapter and why?

Comment: Check you adapter implementation, you pass the collection at the time of adapter initialization. Then how you are going to update the collection inside the adapter from the activity?

Comment: "how you are going to update the collection inside the adapter from the activity" - well, the list is a field (member variable) of the Activity, so it's no problem to add an item to this list in onClick(). The adapter holds on to the list, so changes to the Activity's  list are changes to the Adapter's list.